# Javascript not finding DOM element by ID

Tags: javascript

I have a div on my page:

```
<div id="report"></div>
```

I'm trying to convert a filtered array to nested ULs within that div using this:

```
  let arr = csvData.filter(row => unchecked.includes(row[0]))
  
  console.log(arr);
  
  const div = document.getElementById("report");
  
  const prepareUL = (root, arr) => {
   let ul = document.createElement('ul');
   let li;
   root?.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
   arr.forEach(function(item) {
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
         prepareUL(li, item);
         return;
      };
      li = document.createElement('li');
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
      ul.appendChild(li);
   });
}

  
  prepareUL(div, arr);
```

If I do not check for the existence of the root, I get an error reading appendchild of undefined. I am running the javascript deferred. The array logs properly to the console.
Weirdly, if I just:

```
div.innerHTML = arr;
```

UPDATE: if I change the array to a simple assigned array, like:

```
const arr = [
   'Value 1', ['Inner value 1', 'Inner value 2', 'Inner value 3', 'Inner value 4'],
   'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4', 'Value 5', 'Value 6'
];
```

It also works.

it populates the div with the (unformatted) array. So why would the innerHTML not have an issue finding the element, but the above function cannot?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Switch the positions of the first two elements of `arr`, and you get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `forEach` you call

```
prepareUL(li, item);
```

At that point, `li` is `undefined`, thus inside `prepareUL(root, arr)` `root` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

As connexo pointed out `li` is undefined when you recursively call `prepareUL` function. So creating `li` before calling `prepareUL` is probably the right thing to do.

```js
let arr = ['url', 'url1', ['url2', 'url3', 'url4']]
  
const div = document.getElementById("report"); 

const prepareUL = (root, arr) => {
   let ul = document.createElement('ul');
   root.appendChild(ul);
   arr.forEach(function(item) {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
         prepareUL(li, item);
         ul.appendChild(li);
         return
      };
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
      ul.appendChild(li);
   });
}

  prepareUL(div, arr);
```

```html
<div id="report"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to wait to choose connexo's answer as correct.